# Magento - change "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner"

Tags: magento

is there a manner to change the "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" in Magento Attribute Properties ??

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you change the value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can modify it in the database, but normally it is determined once at the creation of an attribute.

Comment: The column 'frontend_input' in `eav_attribute`. Also make sure your 'backend_type' supports the 'frontend_input' type. This is normally decided by `Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getBackendTypeByInput($frontend_input)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lucasmus, I have modified my Attribute, but I do not understand what to do with : Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getBackendTypeByInput($frontend_input)  and where to use it.

Comment: You don't have to use it, you must ensure that your backend_type supports your frontend_input type and you could use that function for it, but maybe it will be fine. (e.g. if your frontend_input type is 'select' your backend_type should be 'int', as the selected index is stored as integer).

Answer (score 1):

If it is disabled, You can modify it by changing the "frontend_input" field for the respective attribute code in the table "eav_attribute".

Answer (score 1):

12.5 year old question and no up-to-date answer?

Well it just so happens there's a *"hack"* for this. We're all developers right? So this should be easy...

Go to your attribute and under `"Attribute Properties"` find
[image]

Right click and choose "`Inspect"`

Delete the `disabled="disabled"` property in the html, as shown here:
[image]

Now the `"Catalog input Type for Store Owner"` dropdown is useable you can change the Input Type. Click `[SAVE]` and you're done.

**WARNING:**
If you're changing from `"Text Field"` to `"Dropdown"` *(and probably from-to others)*, you will lose all the previously inputed options and will need to start again. I'm using a product feed so I just re-ran it and all was well, but bear this in mind.